# UIViewController: Identify orientation is in progress

Tags: iphone, orientation, progress

I'm developing an iPhone application. Is there any default state/accessor in `UIViewController` that tells if orientation is in progress?

Currently I have done the following:

A `BOOL` member in subclass of `UIViewController` say `isOrientationChangeInProgress`

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
isOrientationChangeInProgress = YES;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
isOrientationChangeInProgress = NO;
}
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple advises starting any animations in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, so he rotation happens soon after that method is called. The duration property tells you how long it takes `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` is called once the rotation is finished, or about duration seconds later.

So, I suppose your BOOL is the best thing to to do in hindsight. I don't understand why you need to know this though; maybe your desired outcome can be achieved a different way. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask to be told device orientation information as well:

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

You then get  told in orientationChanged: when the change happens